# invalid user name and password in asp.net membership login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

i using asp.net web forms membership and i'm create custom login form

```
       if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
         {

       lblLoginMessage.Visible = false;
      // check for role
       if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtUserName.Text, "Admin"))
         {
           FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true);
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin");
         }

        }
       else
        {

          lblLoginMessage.Visible = true;
        }
```

the application was work fine , and a year later login form give me "invalid user name or password " 
the problem is , i backup database and reset password of one of users in users table  using it at local sqlserver database work fine , but when upload the same database to the remote server the user can not login every time give me invalid user name and password , i'm checking islockedout filed in membership table , 
i'm very tired and sad because it is important data and i don't know what can do.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer and I like to share it with you

the reason is when you login from your local machine , asp.net membership make machine key number and when deployment your web site at host , asp.net membership can not found the same machine key ,

the solution is:

add machine key in your local web config project , and create any users you want , then deployment the project , everything work fine ,
you can add machine key in system.web area in web.config

```
 <machineKey validationKey="1234567890123456789012345678901234567890AAAAAAAAAA"
 decryptionKey="123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678"
 validation="SHA1" decryption="Auto" />
 <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```